# How the instance method is being accessible without instantiation of any object?

Tags: python, instantiation

I created a class 'Employee' with two methods as below. I know that these instance methods cannot be accessed by class itself without the instantiation of objects.

But, how the following code works without any instantiation of object?

```
>>> class Employee:
    def __init__(self,name):
        self.name = name
    def getName(self):
        return self.name

>>> Employee('John Doe').getName()       #how this code is working??
'John Doe'
```

I am not seeing any sign of instantiation of object in the code above. But it is working, how?

Comment: `Employee('John Doe')` instantiates an object.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You **do** create an instance. That's what calling the class *does*, it creates an instance:

```
>>> Employee('John Doe')
<__main__.Employee instance at 0x1042bab48>
```

You don't have to *store that instance* to be able to use it in the same expression. By tacking on the `.getName()` attribute lookup and call to the result of the `Employee('John Doe')` part, you are simply chaining looking up the method and calling it into the same statement.

Assignment merely creates a new reference to the instance you just created so you can refer to the instance later; using that named reference later causes Python to retrieve the instance again for you to call the method on.

Compare the output of the following with the above creation of an instance:

```
>>> employee = Employee('John Doe')
>>> employee
<__main__.Employee instance at 0x1042bac68>
```

The only difference is that now I stored the result of creating the instance in a variable with the name `employee`. Using that name again results in the instance being echoed again.

To Python then, there is no difference between using `Employee('John Doe').getName()` and `employee.getName()`, *both* look up the attribute `getName` on the instance and then call it.

Comment: So, it is not mandatory to assign variable(reference name) to the instance to use attributes of class. I hope, I got it.

Comment: @PrakashBhattarai: indeed, it is not required to keep the instance; if all you wanted to do was call one method then that's fine.